# How to access "hidden" attribute of a file in a files input in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, file

I have a file input in HTML,that looks like this:

```
<input name="files" id="theFiles" type="file" />
```

Whenever the user picks a file, I would like to access the "hidden" attribute of said file in the client's local file system, and save it.

Can I do this using Javascript? The file is then transferred as a byte array to the backend via a RESTful API. Is there a way to access this attribute there instead?

Comment: Which "hidden" attribute are you talking about?

Comment: Please elaborate the question further

Comment: @krillgar "hidden" attribute in the client’s local file system, I suppose. If so - no, that is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there is no way to access the information regarding whether a file is hidden in the local file system, using javascript. This is due to security reasons.

 However you can access some of the other metadata by using the File API.
Here is the [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/File)
 which documents the various file metadata that can be accessed using the API.